# contact form 7 mutistep - return to step 1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

i am using contact form 7 a wordpress plugin to create a multi step form. however i need to create a link/button in the last step to return to first step. below are the fieldsets shown in step 3.

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls" data-cf7mls-order="0" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls" data-cf7mls-order="1" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls cf7mls_current_fs" data-cf7mls-order="2" style="height: auto; overflow: visible; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
```

fieldsets shown in step 1.

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls cf7mls_current_fs" data-cf7mls-order="0" style="height: auto; overflow: visible; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls" data-cf7mls-order="1" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
<fieldset class="fieldset-cf7mls" data-cf7mls-order="2" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
```

So basically i need a JS function that will replace the the fieldsets from step 3 to 1 or any other way so the user can return to step 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what is CF7 ? Please put these fieldsets in an minimal example, read more https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In other words: It should be the simplest minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: CF7 = Contact form 7 a wordpress plugin. These fieldsets are generated by the plugin i copied them as is from Chrome inspector. These will aid in the JS function.

Comment: I have edited the question to make clear.

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to use the Smart grid-layout extention which has the ability to create a mutli-slide form as well as exposing js functionality that allows you to control the flow of each slide.  Adding a button on the last slide would be quite easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $("#review-application").click(function(){
        $('.wpcf7-response-output.wpcf7-display-none').removeClass('wpcf7-validation-errors').html('');
        $('.wpcf7-response-output.wpcf7-display-none.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').hide();

        current_fs = $(this).closest('.fieldset-cf7mls');
        previous_fs = $('.fieldset-cf7mls[data-cf7mls-order="0"]');
        current_fs.css({
            height: '0px',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            opacity: '0',
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        }).removeClass('cf7mls_current_fs');
        previous_fs.css({
            height: 'auto',
            overflow: 'visible',
            opacity: '1',
            'visibility': 'visible'
        }).addClass('cf7mls_current_fs');

        var form = $(this).parent().closest('form.wpcf7-form');
        dhScrollTo(form);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: is this your own answer to your question?  If so it would be useful to add some explanations to your code